How to enable animations and transitions in Percy?
An automated Percy test I have created isn't behaving as I would expect. The resulting snapshot looks as though the page hasn't finished loading. So I added waits to the test to ensure page load before the snapshot is taken. However, this did not work.
I think the issue is that there is a very short fade-in CSS animation as the page loads. I have just read about Percy's automatic animation/transition freezing feature. However, I can't find a flag to disable this feature. Is there a way to enable CSS animations in Percy?
